# nginx ingress use k8s secret as HTTP header

Tags: authentication, nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I am using nginx ingress with a setup like this:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: http://api/v1/introspect
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-method: POST
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-response-headers: X-User-Auth
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-snippet: |
  proxy_set_header  auth-header "authheaderhere==";
```

My question is simple but not sure if the answer is:

how can I define the ingress without hardcoding the `auth-header` in the ingress definition?

The introspect endpoint (decodes JWT token and attaches it to original request that is proxied to other microservices) is not exposed outside of the cluster but I want the extra peace of mind knowing that the endpoint, even in the cluster, only responds to authenticated requests (auth-header is a base64 encoded string which contains a client secret and client id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-proxy-set-headers` https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#external-authentication referring to a `ConfigMap` which contains headers.

Here you can find an example https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/customization/custom-headers

Answer (score 0):

> how can I define the ingress without hardcoding the auth-header in the ingress definition?

Develop own controller. An example how to do it is [here](https://www.magalix.com/blog/extending-the-kubernetes-controller).

If you don't want to attach it to Ingress entity - somebody has to.

Own controller can watch existing ingresses (filtered by some your label) and update Ingress Manifests: attach annotations you want.

> The introspect endpoint (decodes JWT token and attaches it to original request that is proxied to other microservices) is not exposed outside of the cluster but I want the extra peace of mind knowing that the endpoint, even in the cluster, only responds to authenticated requests (auth-header is a base64 encoded string which contains a client secret and client id)

If you want to hide your JWT token to Secret - there is no easy way to do it with vanilla Nginx IngressController. [The source](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#external-authentication) says, that:

> `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-snippet`: `<Auth_Snippet>` to specify a custom snippet to use with external authentication, e.g.

i.e. just a sample of nginx config you may include, without additional transformations.

But if you can deploy additional IngressController instance, you can use [`global-auth-snippet`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#global-auth-snippet) parameter there.

Add your snippet to Nginx's ConfigMap. Then create some [IngressClass](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#ingress-class) and add `kubernetes.io/ingress.class=my_ingress_class_name` annotation to your Ingresses (or even [make the class Default](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#default-ingress-class) for cluster)